# Trying to delete all objects older than 7 days in django and I keep getting TypeError: unorderable types: DeferredAttribute() < datetime.datetime()

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a web page that displays a status that is uploaded to a MySQL server from a sonic sensor.

I've tried many different arrangements of the selections but none seem to work.

When I created my first Django project I followed the tutorial and their example, selecting objects created in the past day seemed to work.

```
return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

In my project, I just changed days to 7 and I changed around >= to be <. Then I started getting "TypeError: unorderable types: DeferredAttribute() < datetime.datetime()".

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class garage_door(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)[:19]

    def select_old(self):
        return self.date < timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

My views.py where I am calling this function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from dash.models import garage_door

def dashboard(request):
    garage_door.select_old(garage_door).delete()

    return HttpResponese("Temp Response")
```

I want the program to (as stated above) delete all objects older than 7 days, but for some reason, I get this error. What I got from it is that I am comparing two uncomparable variables, but I don't know how to fix that and I don't even know if my guess about this is correct.

Can it have something to do with the date being added into the table from a different raspberry like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dash_garage_door(date, state) VALUES(%s, %s)"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
val = (now, g_state)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

(The state is either "open" or "closed")

I would be very thankful for any help ! If there is something needed to solve this problem that I haven't provided I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 4):

No it has nothing to do with how the data was inserted. It's that you are not doing a query.

Your method needs to be called on an *instance* of garage_door, and will return whether that particular instance is more than seven days old. But you are calling it on the *class*, apparently expecting it will query the database for all matching items. But that's not how Django works at all.

You need to do this in a filter expression:

```
seven_days_ago = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
garage_door.objects.filter(date__lt=seven_days_ago)
```

You can wrap this into a custom manager:

```
class GarageManager(models.Manager):
    def select_old(self):
        seven_days_ago = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        return self.filter(date__lt=seven_days_ago)

class garage_door(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = GarageManager()
```

Now you can do:

```
garage_door.objects.select_old().delete()
```

Note, according to Python style your model should be called `GarageDoor`, not `garage_door`.